# add upload image to default taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

I am trying to find a way to add a Image to a Taxonomy, in this case, the default one. Tried different solutions, but couldn't find one that answers my needs.

I want to use the Media from WP, and then Upload an image to correspond to a Taxonomy.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

there are several plugins out there that i have used and maybe this might be of help.
Visit https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcustom-category-image/
Download the plugin,upload in your plugins directory on your site then activate it.
Go to categories section you will see image upload section.

To display data on your frontend,either use the options provided by the plugin or use the code below:

```
 $parent_Category=2;
$child_categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0&parent='.$parent_category);


      foreach($child_categories as $cat){

          $cats_id=$cat->term_id;

         $attachment_id   = get_option('categoryimage_'.$cats_id);

          $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id , 'thumbnail' , false ); ?><img src="<?php echo $src[0];?>" /><?php }?>
```

Hope that helps